# Replace Google Play Store Certificate

Tags: java, android, ssl, google-play, google-developers-console

Is there a way to delete the current certificate from Google Play Developer Console and re-upload app with a new certificate?

And if it is possible - will new users, who install app with the new certificate receive updates as usual?

Currently our app is installed only on several devices, so that would not be a problem if our current users wouldn't get updates.

Sorry for my bad English and thanks!

Comment: But wouldn't it be a problem if > 0 users can't ever get updates?

Comment: It would definitely be a problem. )) I thought maybe current users will not get updates and later users with a new certificate will receive updates as usual. Isn't it so?

Comment: I made a change to the text in question. Thanks for pointing out this error in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Google play Store, won't allow to publish updates if the certificate is not the same used to publish the app the first time.